# discord.py music used to work but now im getting an error

Tags: python, discord, bots, audio-player

im not sure what this error is or how to fix it. is it possible to fix or should i just not try.
i searched for this since other people had the same issue, but nothing helped my case.

A while back youtube removed dislike count and recently I tried running an old discord bot when i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Judah Kriss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Judah Kriss\PycharmProjects\discord\main.py", line 25, in play
    await player.queue(url, search=True)
  File "C:\Users\Judah Kriss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\DiscordUtils\Music.py", line 190, in queue
    song = await get_video_data(url, search, bettersearch, self.loop)
  File "C:\Users\Judah Kriss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\DiscordUtils\Music.py", line 92, in get_video_data
    dislikes = data["dislike_count"]
KeyError: 'dislike_count'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Judah Kriss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Judah Kriss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Judah Kriss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'dislike_count'
```

why does the dislike count affect the bot?

the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import DiscordUtils

bot = commands.AutoShardedBot(command_prefix=">")
music = DiscordUtils.Music()


@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()  # Joins author's voice channel


@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()


@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, *, url):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    if not player:
        player = music.create_player(ctx, ffmpeg_error_betterfix=True)
    if not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
        await player.queue(url, search=True)
        song = await player.play()
        await ctx.send(f"Playing {song.name}")
    else:
        song = await player.queue(url, search=True)
        await ctx.send(f"Queued {song.name}")


@bot.command()
async def pause(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = await player.pause()
    await ctx.send(f"Paused {song.name}")


@bot.command()
async def resume(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = await player.resume()
    await ctx.send(f"Resumed {song.name}")


@bot.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    await player.stop()
    await ctx.send("Stopped")


@bot.command()
async def loop(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = await player.toggle_song_loop()
    if song.is_looping:
        await ctx.send(f"Enabled loop for {song.name}")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Disabled loop for {song.name}")


@bot.command()
async def queue(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    await ctx.send(f"{', '.join([song.name for song in player.current_queue()])}")


@bot.command()
async def np(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = player.now_playing()
    await ctx.send(song.name)


@bot.command()
async def skip(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    data = await player.skip(force=True)
    if len(data) == 2:
        await ctx.send(f"Skipped from {data[0].name} to {data[1].name}")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Skipped {data[0].name}")


@bot.command()
async def volume(ctx, vol):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song, volume = await player.change_volume(float(vol) / 100)  # volume should be a float between 0 to 1
    await ctx.send(f"Changed volume for {song.name} to {volume * 100}%")


@bot.command()
async def remove(ctx, index):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = await player.remove_from_queue(int(index))
    await ctx.send(f"Removed {song.name} from queue")

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error shows because the YouTube API no longer exposes the number of dislikes in their API so there is no key called `dislikes`. The issue has been raised but since the owner has abandoned the project there is not going to be a fix. However, another user has forked the repository and continued work on the project so here is what you can do:

Uninstall the old unsupported version:

```
pip uninstall DiscordUtils
```

Install the new branched version which no longer has this error:

```
pip install DiscordUtilsMod
```

Now change you code so that instead of

```
import DiscordUtils
```

Use

```
import DiscordUtilsMod
```